# Making fancy views with Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I should want to make an interface in which i put a UIImageView in the left bottom corner of my main view controller and , if user touch that Image an empty sheet of paper "fly" from it and "land" as an complete interface (with buttons, textfields etc)...
What should be my starting point?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start reading about [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)